# Meteor JS - Nested Functions Returning Value not coming correctly

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor, nested-function

I am using Meteor.JS and [pcel:mysql](https://atmospherejs.com/pcel/mysql) to fetch the mysql result from the method and passing it to the helper.

In my Method, the method is getting executed fine and using connection.query I am able to log the mysql rows in the server side console.

This is what my code looks like:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {

      Meteor.call('mysqltestcall1', function(error, result){
        Session.set('myMethodResult', result);
      });

      Template.hello.helpers({
        data2: function(){
          return Session.get('myMethodResult');
        }
      });

    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {


    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'leaderboard'
    });

    connection.connect();


    Meteor.methods({
    'mysqltestcall1': function(){
    var returnresult = 'test value';
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM players', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(rows);
        returnresult = rows;
    });

    return returnresult;
    }

    });


    }
```

I am getting the value as "test value", but not rows JSON data. Can anyone help me out.

I thing I am not using the variable correctly is in the nested function.

Comment: Wrap this Meteor.call into Template.hello.onCreated function

Comment: I have tried this :

  Template.hello.onCreated(function(){ .......});

But the results are same.

I think it is something that our variable is not getting updated in the nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like connection.query is asynchronous, therefore it has not the time to be executed and the default "returnresult" is instantly returned. 
What if you move the return statement in the query callback?

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM players', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
    return rows;
});
```

Comment: I have tried this also but it is also not working, Thanks for your comment.